# Dotted line on map view

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkpolyline

I can create a line between two points fairly easy with the below code (part of it anyways)  How could I make the line dotted instead of solid?  Also would it be possible to change the opacity the longer the line is?

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay
{
    MKPolylineRenderer *renderer =[[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
    renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    renderer.lineWidth = 3.0;

    return renderer;
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the [`lineDashPattern`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayPathRenderer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013136-CH1-SW14) property to create the pattern you want for the line.

`MKPolylineRenderer` is a subclass of `MKOverlayPathRenderer` which has that property and a few others (see the link to the documentation).

For example, this sets the pattern to a line 2 points long followed by a 5 point gap.  The pattern is repeated for the entire length of the polyline.

```
renderer.lineDashPattern = @[@2, @5];
```

For the opacity, you can either apply an alpha to the `strokeColor`:

```
renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor orangeColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
```

or set the `alpha` property:

```
renderer.alpha = 0.5;
```

Not sure what you mean by "the longer the line is" part of the question.

Comment: Anna, thanks for the help. That makes sense. In regards to the "longer line" I was wondering if its possible to change the alpha value from 1 to .1 within the line itself.  for example the starting point would be an alpha value of 1 and the end point maybe .1

Comment: Varying the alpha along the line would be a gradient and unfortunately that ability isn't built into the standard renderers.  You'll have to create a custom overlay renderer and do the drawing manually.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20159374/467105) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19377748/467105) can help you get started if you want to pursue that path.

Comment: @Anna  great answer..but what if i need the first dash to be small and second dash to be longer and line repeating this pattern ?

Comment: i found it   polylineRenderer.lineDashPattern = [5,10,2,10]

Answer (score 9):

Answer in Swift

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    guard let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline else {
        fatalError("Not a MKPolyline")
    }

    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)

    renderer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.7568627596, alpha: 1)
    renderer.lineWidth = 8
    renderer.lineDashPattern = [0, 10]

    return renderer
}
```

[image]

Comment: Honestly ... should this be an answer? This is just a single line and I don't think anybody will ask to convert it in swift.