# iOS MapKit: Show white dots on polyline route

Tags: ios, mapkit, polyline

Is there a way to show small white dots to indicate transfer points on a route path?

Please suggest. How can I do this?

**Edit:**
Transfer points: those points on route which change the transport mode. Basically, I travel from Boston to Newton with Car, then train, then pickup a bus, so I want to indicate these points with white dots. Is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Make an attempt and come back here with specific questions.

Comment: The transfer points are at _specific_ points along the route (and not just decorative and regularly spaced), right?  Add the transfer points as small MKCircles at the exact coordinates of each transfer point.  They could also be added as annotations with dot images instead of overlays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lineDashPattern property to create the pattern you want for the line.

MKPolylineRenderer is a subclass of MKOverlayPathRenderer which has that property and a few others (see the link to the documentation).

For example, this sets the pattern to a line 2 points long followed by a 5 point gap. The pattern is repeated for the entire length of the polyline.

Find answer on link:-
[Dotted line on map view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572686/dotted-line-on-map-view)

Comment: Thanks For your prompt response. I am looking for other solution. I have updated my question more in brief.